# Port number Change is possible in couchDB -Hyperledger

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I am new in hyperledger technologie. I am use couchDB as the state DB in my hyperledger project. The defaul port of couchDB is use 5984,6984,7984....etc port for couchDB. I need to change couchDB port. I made some change on couchDB port in docker-composer.yaml file. Then I restarted using startFabric.sh file. But it produce error in always.
Please give any idea about it.

OS:Ubuntu 16.04

Fabric:1.1.0

CouchDB:0.4.6

Comment: hi there, there is a Stack Overflow that explains port mapping -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444771/couchdb-port-mapping-in-yaml-file-for-hyperledger-fabric-v1-0-network-setup

Comment: I already visit that page. But that is not equal to my question

Comment: please put in what changes you made and what error you saw.

Comment: and you changed the CouchDB port to match?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785027/couchdb-ip-address-and-port

Comment: yes , I changed CouchDB port from 5984 to 6000. But get some error. Have any idea about it